# Uncommitted memory of process

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have a situation where my 32 bit process (without the \3G flag) reaches over 2GB in size (of type private), and only a small part of it (around 400MB) is committed.

This causes an "out of memory" problem when trying to allocate new memory.

I tried to read about the windows memory structure, but I still am not sure what might have caused the problem. From my understating, any memory which was allocated with the "new" command (in c++) is shown as committed memory.
What can create this situation? and what should I look for in order to solve it? (I don't think its a regular memory leak or else the committed memory was also large)

Here are some odd addresses from vmmap:[image]

Comment: Having a lot of threads would be one way, only the first 2 pages are committed, rest of their 1 MB stack is reserved.  But it is just a blind guessing game without any facts, use SysInternals' VMMap utility to acquire some.

Comment: The description I provided is based on VMMap data.
What other data can help identifying the problem?

Comment: Also, your understanding is flawed - it's perfectly possible to allocate memory that isn't committed with `new` - for example, a large, empty array. Until you actually write something to each of the pages of the array, it's not going to get committed.

Comment: @Luaan Actually, in that case, the memory is committed, but physical memory is not assigned until you access it.

Comment: I have added some data from vmmap specifically in the areas which show large numbers on "Size" and small numbers on "committed".
They are not classified as "Thread stack".
What else can I do in order to get more information about the situation?